# c# Loop List<T> row and trim column values

Tags: c#, list, linq

```
public class Person {
   string Name 
   string Address 
   int Age 
   .. 100+ more columns 
}

var result = new List<Person>();

foreach (var item in result )
{
        //loop column and trim the values.     

}
```

I want the simplest way to loop the columns (assuming 100+ columns) where datatype is string then trim the value.

To rephrase in more C# terms: I want to update all properties and fields of an object that are of type `string` with trimmed value as `item.StringProp = item.StringProp.Trim()`. I don't want to manually write update for each property.

Comment: You cannot Trim integers that are also part of your columns. If you have columns of other types, i am sure you'll have the same issue as well.

Comment: Paul, I've added C# version of your question - please review and update as necessary. Usually object fields/properties are not called "columns"... which presumably why you did not find any similar posts showing access to all properties/fields of unknown objects...

Answer (score 4):

You could use reflection and Linq for filtering the properties of type string. From the OP, it looks like you are using Fields instead of properties. Please note it is unclear whether the Properties/Fields are public from OP, if you need to use public fields/properties, please use BindingFlags.Public

```
public List<T> TrimList<T>(List<T> source)
{
    foreach(var property in  typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x=>x.FieldType== typeof(string)))
    {
        foreach(var personItem in source)
            property.SetValue(personItem,Convert.ToString(property.GetValue(personItem)).Trim());
    }
    return source;
}
```

If properties, you could use

```
public List<T> TrimList<T>(List<T> source)
{
    foreach(var property in  typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x=>x.PropertyType== typeof(string)))
    {
        foreach(var personItem in source)
            property.SetValue(personItem,Convert.ToString(property.GetValue(personItem)).Trim());
    }
    return source;
}
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LPck9G)

Note: prior to .NET 4.5 you need to pass null as a second argument:

```
public List<T> TrimList<T>(List<T> source)
{
    foreach(var property in  typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x=>x.PropertyType== typeof(string)))
    {
        foreach(var personItem in source)
            property.SetValue(personItem,Convert.ToString(property.GetValue(personItem,null)).Trim());
    }
    return source;
}
```

Comment: How does this work for a property that is of another class?

Comment: @Jawad Please check the updated answer. Also, the trim is done only for fields/properties of type string

Comment: I tested it with a string and an int, didnt work for the string, You are taking List<T> as an input and getting the properties of that List. Wont work I believe

Comment: I'm having issue with the code. Im using .net framework 3.5

Comment: @Jawad you probably had a public field/property, It is unclear from OP whether it is public. which is why i have used BindingFlags.Non-Public.

Comment: @PaulWhite - could you be more specific ? what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: You are right.. didnt even see that. I changed it to public and worked.

Comment: No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @PaulWhite Please check the updated answer. For version 3.5, you need to pass null as second arguement.

Answer (score 0):

As well as reflection, another way is to make it the responsibility of the Person class.

```
public class Person {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; } 
   .. 100+ more columns 

  public void DoTrim()
  {
      this.Name = this.Name.Trim();
      this.Address = this.Address.Trim();
      ... still need to code 100+ properties
  }
}
```

The advantage is that you can call it like this

```
var result = new List<Person>();
...
for(int i=0; i < result.Count(); i++)
{           
    result[i].DoTrim();
}
```

Or you can control your data in the Person class when you set it and use local private variables.

```
public class Person {
   private string name;
   public string Name
   {
       get { return name; }
       set { name = value.Trim(); }
   }

   private string address;
   public string Address
   {
       get { return address; }
       set { address= value.Trim(); }
   }
....
```

Comment: For extra credit, use reflection to compile a lambda expression....

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implement it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Person
        {
            MyProperty = " A",
            MyProperty1 = " A ",
            MyProperty2 = "A ",
            MyProperty3 = "A A A",
        };
        TrimStrings(obj);
    }

    public static void TrimStrings(object obj)
    {
        Type stringType = typeof(string);
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == stringType);
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            string value = (string)property.GetValue(obj);
            property.SetValue(obj, value?.Trim());
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

> {"MyProperty":"A","MyProperty1":"A","MyProperty2":"A","MyProperty3":"A
>   A A"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [This Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdjustStringProperties/)
.After Install use it as bellow:

```
result.ForEach(x => x.AdjustString());
```